# Server perfomance baseline

Tags: linux, networking

I am working to get some base line server performance and network device performance. Is there any way to do that ?

```
exp: calculate base line load average 
     calculate base line  mem utilization. 
     calculate base line   io
```

So that we can compare the current value with the baseline value to see if there some issue or difference.

Comment: Monitor each, stick the results on a graph, and establish a baseline. Will be different for different applications and use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to install the `sysstat` package and use the `sar` command to monitor/get performance data.

That said, it is difficult to exactly define what do you call "server baseline performance"...